# Different d3 versions causing dependency issues when used within Shiny app

Tags: r, d3.js, shiny, dependencies

I'm trying to incorporate three plots in shiny, all of which use the d3 library. On placing them in different tabPanels(or the same one for that matter), I see only one or two plots, and they do not react properly. One of the plots is pulled from 'pp.html' and is based on d3.v3.min.js library. Second plot is pulled from 'australian.html' and it uses d3.v4.js library. The third plot is created using scatterD3 library of R.

A minimum working example is given below:

ui.R

```
shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
      navbarPage("You Got Served!", id = "page",
      tabPanel("Overall Analysis", value = "panel1",
                  h2(textOutput("title")),
                  scatterD3Output("scatter", width = "1500", height = "700"),
                  br()),
      tabPanel("Parallel Coordinate", value = "panel2",
               fluidRow(
                   column(2, 
                          uiOutput("pc", width = 700, height = 600), 
                          br())
                 )),
      tabPanel("Sunburst", value= "panel3",
                          suppressDependencies("d3.v3.min.js"),
                          uiOutput("gs"),
                              br(),
                              hr())
)))
```

server.R

```
 shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

 session$onSessionEnded({stopApp})
 output$scatter <- renderScatterD3({

   dat <- mydata %>%
     mutate(FirstServePercent = (w_1stIn/w_svpt) * 100, MatchDuration = 
minutes, Hand = winner_hand) %>%
     select(FirstServePercent, MatchDuration, Hand, Surface = surface, 
Tournament = tourney_name)

   s1 <- scatterD3(data = dat, y = FirstServePercent, x = MatchDuration, 
col_var = Surface, symbol_var = Hand, point_size = 70, labels_size = 30, 
xlab = "Match Duration (in minutes)", ylab = "First Serve %", axes_font_size 
= "15px", legend_font_size = '20', point_opacity = 0.5, hover_size = 1.8, 
hover_opacity = 1, transition = TRUE)

   s1
   })

 output$gs <- renderUI({
   return(htmlTemplate("australian.html"))})

 output$pc <- renderUI({

     return(htmlTemplate("pp.html"))})

})
```

I tried to find examples relating to the usage of suppressDependencies() function in R, but was not able to find any working ones. I want to know where exactly should I use that function to render the three charts correctly, with their relevant interactions. If the solution involves using a functionality other than suppressDependencies, I'll really appreciate that too.

A part of the dataset mydata looks something like this:

[image: mydata]

Comment: You could put the html ones in iframes to prevent any issues. Something like `tags$iframe(src='pp.html',width="100%",frameBorder="0",height="500px")`

Comment: I don't see `mydata` anywhere.

Comment: @NicE Shall I insert the iframe chunk you suggested in ui.R or server.R? It'll be really helpful if you can make the necessary edit in my code itself. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use iframes in your `renderUi` to avoid dependencies issues:
plot is pulled from 'australian.html' and it uses d3.v4.js library. The third plot is created using scatterD3 library of R.

```
output$gs <- renderUI({
    tags$iframe(src='australian.html',width="100%",frameBorder="0",heigh‌​t="500px")
})

output$pc <- renderUI({    
    tags$iframe(src='pp.html',width="100%",frameBorder="0",heigh‌​t="500px")    
})
```

Comment: Sorta following the above example, if you were going to have multiple "australian.html" or "pp.html" files, that are displayed based upon a given input, would doing so require all possible plots to be pre-rendered prior to launching the shiny app? i.e. having `australian_001.html`, `australian_002.html`, etc. files in some sort of directory within the `www` folder?